# Android App Startup Crash - customtabs.CustomTabsSession.validateRelationship

Tags: java, android

I followed Googles guidelines for the recent [Trusted Web Activities](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa) and my app has been working fine on my device and some select emulators.

However, on certain devices and emulators (such as Google Pixel 2) I get an immediate crash on startup.

The logcat outputs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ocdev.yu_gi_ohdatabase, PID: 5020
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsSession.validateRelationship(int, android.net.Uri, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.customtabs.TrustedWebUtils.launchAsTrustedWebActivity(TrustedWebUtils.java:134)
        at android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity$TwaCustomTabsServiceConnection.onCustomTabsServiceConnected(LauncherActivity.java:199)
        at android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(CustomTabsServiceConnection.java:44)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1634)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1663)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ocdev.yu_gi_ohdatabase">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ygo_fore"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ygo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
        <activity
            android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity">

            <!-- Edit android:value to change the url opened by the TWA -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
                android:value="https://db.ygoprodeck.com" />

            <!-- This intent-filter adds the TWA to the Android Launcher -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!--
              This intent-filter allows the TWA to handle Intents to open
              airhorner.com.
            -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <!-- Edit android:host to handle links to the target URL-->
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="db.ygoprodeck.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ocdev.yu_gi_ohdatabase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.GoogleChrome.custom-tabs-client:customtabs:3a71a75c9f'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```

Project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I also tested my release apk on Android Emulators via [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) and I receive the exact same issue. 
I also received the issue on some physical devices I test such as Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge but the strange thing is that I tested a different Galaxy S7 Edge and it worked without issues. From what I have tested so far, I'd guess it works on 50% of the devices I've tested.
I'm not an inherit Android developer so I am struggling to find the cause of this issue and why it works fine and some devices and not on others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question on the Chromium forums and got redirected to a temporary fix listed [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=928701).

In short, they are aware of the issue and hope to have a permanent solution out soon so the temporary fix shouldn't be needed for long.

The answer given:

> For the moment, you can change the last parameter to
>   CustomTabsClient#getPackageName [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/custom-tabs-client.git/+/7ab7178ae0c4858d15b1918bded4dd5cac758870/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/trusted/LauncherActivity.java#86) to true. This parameter is
>   'ignoreDefault' and as you can probably guess will make the package
>   selection ignore the user's default. Ideally though this won't be
>   necessary for long.

Comment: Bumping `custom-tabs-client` to suggested in the thread version seems to solve the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

I noticed that if I update chrome to the last version (currently 72) the TWA works great. 
What is annoying is that there is no error message for the user to make him update chrome.

IMO this makes TWA currently not usable.

Comment: It's apparently supposed to use a fall back if the user isn't on Chrome 72, this working is completely device dependent for me: Today, if the user's version of Chrome doesn't support Trusted Web activities, Chrome will fall back to a simple toolbar using a Custom Tab. It is also possible for other browsers to implement the same protocol that Trusted Web activities use. While the host app has the final say on what browser gets opened, we recommend the same policy as for Custom Tabs: use the user's default browser, so long as that browser provides the required capabilities.

Comment: I have Chrome 76 installed and still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue with my TWA too, I found that if the browser default is set to chrome or edge then it'll work but not for samsung browser and firefox

Answer (score -1):

This issue may not happen anymore with the new versions. However, if someone still uses old versions, updating to the new version can be helped.
In the new version the validate function has been removed as explain:

> Allow to send multiple trusted origins from TWA clients
>   Currently, if the user is able to navigate or gets redirected to
>   another trusted origin within a TWA, the only way to ensure that the
>   other origin gets verified is by calling
>   CustomTabsSession#verifyRelationship on the client side. Besides being
>   a bit awkward api, that would delay launching Chrome, and
>   consequently, showing splash screen, so this needs to change.

Please check this answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58231296/4446181