# NullPointerException when using Trusted Web Activities on Android (multiple devices)

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I'm using [TrustedWebActivities](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa) and I'm getting an immediate app crash on Samsung S8, S9, and Pixel 2 devices with the below Exception.  Some research suggests that this might happen on devices where there's an older version of Chrome installed which doesn't support TWA and the fall-back method fails. But I've confirmed that the Chrome version is 71 (also, this works on Samsung S7, Pixel 3).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.support.customtabs.TrustedWebUtils.launchAsTrustedWebActivity (TrustedWebUtils.java:91)
  at android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity$TwaCustomTabsServiceConnection.onCustomTabsServiceConnected (LauncherActivity.java:192)
  at android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection.onServiceConnected (CustomTabsServiceConnection.java:44)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1656)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1685)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I believe this is happening on this line where `session` is null, which is an object of type `CustomTabsSession`. Here's the [source](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/23a570c65c45ad19725b53359c2556156b9a4363/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/TrustedWebUtils.java).

```
  session.validateRelationship(CustomTabsService.RELATION_HANDLE_ALL_URLS, uri, null);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of the Support Library are you using? Are you using the LauncherActivity provided with the Support Library (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/trusted/LauncherActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

this issue has been fixed as commit 
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/commit/51a4ff1d07d8507b934fc9d9af226a969b6c4674?diff=split#diff-39c75633d34184d98d2495b5686172dbL132-R136

you can update the version in gradefile, it should work

`implementation 'com.github.GoogleChrome.custom-tabs-client:customtabs:d08e93fce3fb3e1f22214ee2f23fddc4f4e92634'`

as you can check the diff, the validate function has been deleted.

```
session.validateRelationship(CustomTabsService.RELATION_HANDLE_ALL_URLS, uri, null);
```

However, as google team mention on readme that we should use Adnroid Browser Helper instead.

`Please use the Android Browser Helper library instead. It contains the same functionality updated to work with AndroidX.`

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper